# OpenLDAP TLS vs SSL

Tags: ssl, openldap

I'm experimenting with OpenLDAP replication. I'm using a Docker image:

https://github.com/osixia/docker-openldap

to spawn a couple of containers that are talking to each other. The default configuration for the container is to use TLS for client connectivity and replication. I could go thru the exercise and configure SSL certificates and keys but I'm not sure if this is necessary.

According to this FAQ:
http://www.openldap.org/faq/data/cache/605.html TLS over LDAP is the preferred method of replication over LDAPS.

What are the security implications of replicating over TLS vs SSL?

Comment: TLS uses certificates the same way SSL does, so if thats why you are asking, it makes no differance between the two. If you are already using TLS, that implies that you don't need to generate anything for SSL to work, but SSL is an older broken protocol, and TLS1.1-1.2 are what are currently safe-enough-for-use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TLS is the successor of SSL, so basically they should behave both the same way. What changes are specifications making TLS a more secure version of SSL. **Never use SSLv2 or SSLv3**, as they are broken.

TLS is just the next version of the SSL protocol. It's important to note that certificates are independent of protocols: If you use a correct certificate it should work both with SSL and TLS.